SQL Server reclaim or destroy unused threads
Sometimes our production SQL Server encounters high amount heavy queries that stem from malicious user usage. While this doesn't affect CPU usage by much(as in CPU time), it will spike the CPU thread count to a very high level, and this lasts for around 30 minutes even though the queries are only executed for around 2 minutes. From what we know, this is a common SQLServer mechanism that keep those threads around, expecting further usage.
While the actual issue is being addressed from infrastructure level and restricting users through SOP, is there any way to request SQLServer to instantly reclaim/destroy those unused threads or speed up the reclaimation process?
Edit: We are using SQLServer 2017 Enterprise edition

So what issue do you have with those threads hanging around? Do they cause slowdown for you? Do they trigger some monitoring that you have?

@rois Nothing that affects operations in particular since the queries are long completed at that point. They do however trigger multiple monitoring systems as you guessed.

What kind of malicious usage there is? You should look into ways to prevent that before it affects the database. As how to do that really depends on how it happens: are users running ad hoc queries via SSMS, is there a website that gets DoSed, developers running tests on production or whatever?

@vonPryz It's DDoS through a loophole in the system, the issue is already in process of being fixed, we're just looking for a way to deal the effects in the meantime

You could try setting SQL Server to only use one CPU briefly, then set it back to the default. Which CPU you choose depends on where the excessive worker threads currently are. Workers on disallowed CPUs should be trimmed fairly rapidly.
For example:
ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION SET PROCESS AFFINITY CPU = 0;
GO
ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION SET PROCESS AFFINITY CPU = AUTO;
GO

Less disruptively, you could move work off one core at a time using a sequence of such steps.

We tested this, but even when we set SQLServer to only use one CPU, the threads are still held by the other CPU. The same thing happens even if we didnt set it back to AUTO
